# Retrieve and echo greek characters problem

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, internationalization, data-retrieval

Lets say I have a string like this - " Πρώτη θέση   Δεύτερη θέση"
Using php DOM tree I search for elements td and I am trying to echo Πρώτη Θέση and Δεύτερη Θέση. Although when I am echoing the Greek characters do not appear regularly. Instead I get some weird symbols!

I have already set the appropriate encoding. I think the problem is caused during the retrieval.

Comment: Please show the code you are using, including the parts where you set the encoding

Comment: What do you mean by "trying to echo"?

Comment: <html lang="el"><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></head> //This is the main, but I have tried three different for Greek characters. 

I want to read the part I told you and then echo it in my page without the <td>,</td> parts

Comment: I cannot add the whole code because is quite big. Something like this:  s = "<td> Πρώτη Θέση </td> <td> Δεύτερη Θέση </td>; I open the DOM and search for the elements td and I echo to my page only  Πρώτη Θέση and Δεύτερη Θέση.

Comment: Have you set the appropriate encoding in the php headers, not just in a meta tag?

Comment: maybe not... give me some more info plz

Answer (score 1):

the following code works for me!

```
<html>
<head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"></head>
<body>
<?php
   $string = "Πρώτη θέση Δεύτερη θέση";
   echo $string;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Cheers